# jQuery form submit not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, submit

I've looked at all the question on SO about this, and can't find the solution.  I have a form that gets appended to the DOM via an AJAX call, and upon successful completion, I connect the form submittal to a javascript method.  Works fine in Chrome.  Doesn't call my javascript method in Firefox 20 or 21.

```
    $("#dateList").load("/chargeback/cb_timeentry/te_list/" + empId, function() {
        $("#addEntryDate").submit(function() {
            addEntryDate();
            return false;   
        });
    });
```

Form, rendered by Django, looks like this (in both FF and Chrome):

```
<div id="addOrDelete">
    <input id="addEntryDateButton" type="submit" value="+">
    <input id="deleteEntryDateButton" type="submit" disabled="true" value="-">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <form id="addEntryDate" class="uiText" method="get" action="."></form>
                <form id="deleteEntryDateForm" class="uiText" method="get" action="."></form>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
```

The form as written in the Django template, is like this:

```
<div id="addOrDelete">
<table>
    <tr>
        <form id="addEntryDate"  class="uiText" action="." method="get">
            <input id="addEntryDateButton" type="submit" value="+" disabled="true" />
        </form>
        <form id="deleteEntryDateForm" class="uiText" action="." method="get">
            <input id="deleteEntryDateButton" type="submit" value="-" disabled="true"/>
        </form>
        </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The load call works fine in Firefox, with the correct HTML showing my button type=submit inside the addEntryDate form.  The load hits the submit line, addEntryDate is in the DOM, but when I click it, it doesn't call the addEntryDate() javascript method.  What do I do?

Comment: Please provide your form code. Are there any errors in the Firefox console when executing the whole process?

Comment: edited to show form code.  No errors or warnings in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Django but at the first look at the rendered code I think that it should never work.

`input submit` should be within the `form` element in order to provide the default (browser supported) form submission. But if it works anyway, then Django probably add some javascript code that links mouseclick javascript event to the correct form subbmition.

It's quite possible, because the form rendered by Django template works and the form created by you (via AJAX) is not working correctly.

Search in the redendered page if there is some jQuery/plain Javascript/etc. code that can possibly be resposible for your form subbmition and try to duplicate that in your AJAX-based form.

If it's not there then the first form shouldn't be even submitted in the first place and I've no idea why it would work in Chrome.

But at least you can write simple jQuery to do this:

```
    $("#dateList").load("/chargeback/cb_timeentry/te_list/" + empId, function() {
        $(document).on("click", "#addEntryDateButton", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $("#addEntryDate").submit();
        });

        $("#addEntryDate").submit(function() {
            addEntryDate();
            return false;   
        });
    });
```

Comment: Django doesn't add any script to the page - it's static html once rendered, but it turns out the HTML rendering is the issue.  Removing the forms and using plain vanilla javascript onclick functionality solves the issue.  I'll accept your answer as it correctly identifies the html as the issue

Answer (score 0):

My guess : you already had an element on the page with the ID `addEntryDate` and Firefox doesn't recognise the new one as owning the ID but Chrome has chosen to give it priority.

Don't write code which results in two elements with the same ID - and look out for dynamic DOM manipulation which causes it, it's an easy mistake to make with `.load()`.

Comment: I got bit by that previously.  Not what's happening in this case.